# Why not work POST method in retrofit in Android

Tags: android, android-studio, android-proguard

I want use Retrofit library for Post and Get methods from server. When use `proGuard` and generate APK not running my Post codes!
**My Register codes:**

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.register_button:
                name = registerName.getText().toString();
                email = registerEmail.getText().toString();
                password = registerPassword.getText().toString();
                if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
                    if (password.length() < 6) {
                        Snackbar.make(getView(), "", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        registerLoad.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        registerSend.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        registerProcess(name, email, password);
                    }
                } else {
                    Snackbar.make(getView(), "Fill all fields", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                break;
        }
    }

    private void registerProcess(String name, String email, String password) {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .setLenient()
                .create();

        OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

        Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(Constants.BASE_URL)
                .client(client)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();

        Retrofit_ApiInterface requestInterface = retrofit.create(Retrofit_ApiInterface.class);

        User user = new User();
        user.setName(name);
        user.setEmail(email);
        user.setPassword(password);

        ServerRequest request = new ServerRequest();
        request.setOperation(Constants.REGISTER_OPERATION);
        request.setUser(user);

        Call<ServerResponse> response = requestInterface.operation(request);
        response.enqueue(new Callback<ServerResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ServerResponse> call, Response<ServerResponse> response) {
                try {
                    ServerResponse resp = response.body();
                    if (resp.getResult() != null && resp.getResult().equals("success")) {
                        Snackbar.make(getView(), StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(resp.getMessage()), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        goToLogin();
                        registerLoad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        registerSend.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        registerSend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        Snackbar.make(getView(), StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml4(resp.getMessage()), Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.e("registerException", "" + e);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ServerResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                registerLoad.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                registerSend.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                Snackbar.make(getView(), "Try again", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }

    private void goToLogin() {

        Fragment login = new LoginFragment();
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.replace(R.id.loginFragment, login);
        ft.commit();
        toolbarTitle.setText("login");
        registerFAB.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_login_add));
    }
}
```

**My proguard ruls :**

```
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
```

When use `GET` methods not show me error, but when use `POST` method show me error! 
In my code, when register **"success"** or **"failure"** should message from server and show in `Snackbar`. but when generate APK with `proguard` not show me any message in `Snackbar`!

I added below codes in proguard-rules for not obfuscate my models and interface, but now work me again and not show anymessage from server.

```
-dontwarn com.test.app.Retrofit.Rest.**
-dontwarn com.test.app.Retrofit.Model.User.**
```

How can I fix this problem? please help me, I really need this help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
##---------------Begin: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------
# Gson uses generic type information stored in a class file when working with fields. Proguard
# removes such information by default, so configure it to keep all of it.
-keepattributes Signature

# For using GSON @Expose annotation
-keepattributes *Annotation*

# Gson specific classes
-keep class sun.misc.Unsafe { *; }
#-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

# Application classes that will be serialized/deserialized over Gson
-keep class your.package.Models.** { *; }

# Prevent proguard from stripping interface information from TypeAdapterFactory,
# JsonSerializer, JsonDeserializer instances (so they can be used in @JsonAdapter)
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer


 ##---------------End: proguard configuration for Gson  ----------

    # Platform calls Class.forName on types which do not exist on Android to determine platform.
    -dontnote retrofit2.Platform
    # Platform used when running on Java 8 VMs. Will not be used at runtime.
    -dontwarn retrofit2.Platform$Java8
    # Retain generic type information for use by reflection by converters and adapters.
    -keepattributes Signature
    # Retain declared checked exceptions for use by a Proxy instance.
    -keepattributes Exceptions
```

use the above rules for retrofit to work with progaurd
**Note: you are supposed to keep your model classes as well here -keep class your.package.Models.** { *; } **have suitable name**